# Knockout change models in template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

First I'm new to using knockout.

I have bound array1 to my template now I would like change it to use array2 is this possible with knockout?

What I was messing with

```
  var viewModel = function(){
    var _this = this;
    this.test = [{ name: 'Fruit4'}, {name: 'Vegetables'}];
    this.categories = ko.observableArray(this.test);
    this.changeItems = function()
    {
       this.test= [{ name: 'Fruit2'}, {name: 'Vegetables2'}];
       categories = ko.observableArray(this.test);     
    }
  };

  ko.applyBindings(viewModel());
```

Comment: where are the array1 and array2 ? I can't see them. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a computed observable that will return one of the two arrays based on your conditions whatever they would be and bind to it.  Make sure that the conditions that decide which to choose are also observable so it will update properly.

```
function ViewModel(data) {
    this.array1 = ko.observableArray(data.array1);
    this.array2 = ko.observableArray(data.array2);

    // change this value to true to use array2
    this.chooseArray2 = ko.observable(false);

    this.array = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.chooseArray2()
            ? this.array2()
            : this.array1();
    }, this);
}
```

```
<div data-bind="foreach: array">
    ...
</div>
```

Of course the logic could be more complex than that.  To be more manageable, I would make the condition observable computed as well and create the logic in there.  The computed observable that returns the array wouldn't have to change much.

```
function ViewModel(data) {
    this.array1 = ko.observableArray(data.array1);
    this.array2 = ko.observableArray(data.array2);

    // which to choose depends on a number of conditions
    this.someCondition = ko.observable(false);
    this.anotherCondition = ko.observable(true);
    this.someNumber = ko.observable(132);
    this.chooseArray2 = ko.computed(function () {
        // some complex logic
        if (this.someNumber() < 0) {
            return this.someCondition();
        }
        return this.someCondition() || !this.anotherCondition();
    }, this);

    this.array = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.chooseArray2()
            ? this.array2()
            : this.array1();
    }, this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer this worked perfectly.  I made a jsFiddle with just quick example on how i intend to use it. http://jsfiddle.net/fuW8L/